# Unable to conditionally render React Native screens using Firebase Firestore, citing "missing return"

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a group project in React Native, and we have a page called `EventListScreen.js`, which is called by a tab navigator. Inside this file, we display a list of events which are called from Firebase Cloud Firestore database. We want to conditionally display this page with an "add event" button depending on whether the user is a "Volunteer" or an "Organization."

Here's the full code for the file, so as to not leave anything out.

```
const EventListScreen = (props) => {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("events")
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const events = [];
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          const { address, eName } = doc.data();
          events.push({
            id: doc.id,
            address,
            eName,
          });
        });
        setEvents(events);
      });
  }, []);

  const OrganizationScreen = () => {
    <ScrollView>
      <Button
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("AddEvent")}
        title="Add Event"
      />
      {events.map((event) => {
        return (
          <ListItem
            key={event.id}
            bottomDivider
            onPress={() => {
              props.navigation.navigate("EventDetails", {
                userId: event.id,
              });
            }}
          >
            <ListItem.Chevron />
            <ListItem.Content>
              <ListItem.Title>{event.uId}</ListItem.Title>
              <ListItem.Title>{event.address}</ListItem.Title>
              <ListItem.Title>{event.eName}</ListItem.Title>
            </ListItem.Content>
          </ListItem>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>;
  };

  const VolunteerScreen = () => {
    {/* ... the same thing as the above without the <Button> element ... */}
  };

  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.data().accountType == "Volunteer") {
        return VolunteerScreen();
      } else {
        return OrganizationScreen();
      }
    });
};

export default EventListScreen;
```

Are there any alternatives to displaying two types of HTML depending on what kind of user is detected from Firebase? Very basically: we just want to remove or deactivate that button when the user type is of "Volunteer." This method shown above, and a few other syntactic derivatives, will result in an error where React believes there is no return to render.

**EDIT**

Here's what it looks like when I put a log statement in the Firebase part fo the logic. It can correctly identify that the user is of "Volunteer" type, but it gives the error with explanation "Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null." This can be resolved by putting a simple return statement after the Firebase bit, but this seems to overrides the other HTML we wanted to render.

So... maybe there is some sort of scope issue here?

[image: docdata]

Comment: Can you check if the accountType in Firestore is `"Volunteer"` and not `"volunteer"` ?

Comment: It is capitalized `Volunteer` and not `volunteer`

Comment: Can you try logging `doc.data()` and share a screenshot ?

Comment: Edited to show so

Comment: @tteumul did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you have implemented have made things complex.

Have a flow like below
in useEffect first load the user type then load the events, based on the userType render the button, until the user is loaded show an ActivityIndicator, the code should be like below.

```
const EventListScreen = (props) => {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const [userType,setUserType]=useState();

  useEffect(() => {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
       setUserType(doc.data().accountType);
      firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("events")
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const events = [];
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          const { address, eName } = doc.data();
          events.push({
            id: doc.id,
            address,
            eName,
          });
        });
        setEvents(events);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  if(!userType)
   return <ActivityIndicator/>;

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {
        //if this is true button would be shown
        userType!=='Volunteer' && <Button
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("AddEvent")}
        title="Add Event"
      />
      }
      {events.map((event) => {
        return (
          <ListItem
            key={event.id}
            bottomDivider
            onPress={() => {
              props.navigation.navigate("EventDetails", {
                userId: event.id,
              });
            }}
          >
            <ListItem.Chevron />
            <ListItem.Content>
              <ListItem.Title>{event.uId}</ListItem.Title>
              <ListItem.Title>{event.address}</ListItem.Title>
              <ListItem.Title>{event.eName}</ListItem.Title>
            </ListItem.Content>
          </ListItem>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```